# How to make a rule so a function can only be run once by each user js react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a like button sorta thing where a use can like a review but I want each user to only be able to like each review once.

```
 const handleHelpfulButtonClick = () => {
    console.log(review)
    props.dispatch(incrementingTheHelpfulScore(review.helpful_score + 1, review.id, review.property_ID))
    props.refresh()
}
```

The function above increments the score

```
{ (isUserId !== review.user_ID) &&
            <button onClick={() => handleHelpfulButtonClick(review.helpful_score)} className="button is-info">Helpful</button>

}
```

This makes it so a user cannot like a post which they have created and calls the above function

Comment: Set up a counter to equal 1 and check if the counter is over 1.

Comment: Do you have a localStorage/Database? Where do you want to keep those changes?

Answer (score 0):

you can store the `executed` state in your localStorage if you don't want to read that state from API or something else...

e.g:

```
const runOnce = () => {
   const excutedState = localStorage.getItem("executed");
   if (excutedState === undefined) alert("welcome");
   localStorage.setItem("executed", "true");
}
```